# Problem loading ajax in the header

Tags: ajax

Im using this tutorial http://digwp.com/2009/07/display-a-random-post-with-ajax-refresh/# to create a section on my homepage where I can refresh a section with ajax. I have it all setup but the post is not loading on page load. I found a line in the page source that says...

```
<script type="text/javascript">var ajaxurl = "http://mysite.com/wp-load.php";   </script>
```

The `</script>` isn't highlighted like the beginning `<script>` so I'm wondering if that's the problem. Any idea why that is?

Comment: You should be localizing that and using admin-ajax.php anyways. Read [this article](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/) for correct implementation.

Comment: Hmmm ok that tutorial went over my head. What changes should I apply to the tutorial above to make it work properly?

Comment: @m0r7if3r you should post that as an *answer*.

Comment: I felt like it was a bit skimpy to be considered an answer...but done.

Answer (score 1):

You should be localizing that and using admin-ajax.php anyways. Read [this article](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/) for correct implementation.